# Re-publish an item already be published before

Tags: web8, publishing

We used to have one choice in the publish setting, for all selected items, only re-publish the item which be published before. This option seems disappeared at SDL Web 8. Could anyone show me how we can do this operation right now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only get this option when publishing an Organizational item (like a Structure Group or a Publication) or an item that resolves into a group  of items (like a Page/Component Template), rather than individual Pages.

See also https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-C9EF0813-2B50-4227-BA88-17AA893161E3 step 4 of the procedure on that page, explains the Republish Only option.

Comment: And I think this was always the case - when you select a page (or a group of pages) you obviously want to publish those irrelevant of previous status (otherwise why would you select them?)

Comment: The same option is present for Component Templates and Page Templates. Possibly for Bundles as well, don't recall from the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

You can send every item to republish via CoreService.
You can user in your publish instruction ResolvePurpose.RePublish
It can be something like this:

```
 private PublishInstructionData publishInstructionData = new PublishInstructionData()
    {
        ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData()
        {
            Purpose = ResolvePurpose.RePublish
        },
        RenderInstruction = new RenderInstructionData(),
    };
```

If you want to integrate this in GUI, you can always create GUI Extension that will execute this piece of code.